# Error linking C code when including SQLite

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio, sqlite, clang

On Visual Studio Code, Mac OS version 10 I am trying to compile (debug C/C++ file) a C code to connect to SQLite3 database. The compile ends with error :

> ld: library not found for -lsqlite clang: error: linker command failed
> with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

There is an SQLite3 folder under /usr/lib/ , which includes the SQLite3 library. sqlite3.h I put directly under the same source code file sqlite3test1.c. However the compile failed with an error. I link using this command on terminal :

```
/usr/bin/clang -lsqlite3 -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /Users/Training/sqlite3test1.c -o /Users/Training/sqlite3test1
```

The command generated an executable file, run correctly, and the executable file provided the database records on the terminal window ( Success ).

How to make the link without the command?

Comment: The VS Code error shows you seem to be incorrectly using `-lsqlite` instead of `-lsqlite3`

Comment: Put `-lsqlite3` at the end of the command line, not near the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is included in macOS and Mac OS X by default. So I think you are asking where to add your `-lsqlite3` link parameter in the VSCode right? If so, there is a hidden folder `.vscode`, inside is a `tasks.json`:

[image: Project Explorer on the Sidebar]

Open `task.json`:

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "args": [
            "-fcolor-diagnostics",
            "-fansi-escape-codes",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "args": [
            "-fcolor-diagnostics",
            "-fansi-escape-codes",
            "-g",
            "-l",
            "sqlite3",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang"
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Did you find the `sqlite3` command I added? That's it.

Now if you build and run the `main.c` file, VSCode will compile&link successfully, and you are ready to debug.

[image]